# Query takes too long to query with OR clause but their parts are very quick

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance

I have two tables with ~1M rows indexed by their Id's.

the fallowing query...

```
SELECT t.* FROM transactions t
INNER JOIN integration it ON it.id_trans = t.id_trans
WHERE t.id_trans = '5440073'
OR it.id_integration = '439580587'
```

This query takes about 30s. But ...

```
SELECT ... WHERE t.id_trans = '5440073'
```

takes less than 100ms and

```
SELECT ... WHERE it.id_integration = '439580587'
```

also takes less than 100ms. Even

```
SELECT ... WHERE t.id_trans = '5440073'
UNION
SELECT ... WHERE it.id_integration = '439580587'
```

takes less then 100ms

Why does the `OR` clause takes so much time even if the parts being so fast?

Comment: _"What should I do to improve the performance of this query?"_ You already did it; splitting up such problematic OR conditions into joined queries is one of the standard ways of dealing with this scenario. The problem is caused because MySQL cannot use both indexes in one (non-UNIONed) query.

Comment: Interesting, Uueerdo. Is this specific to MySQL?

Comment: I'm only intimately familiar with it on MySQL, but a quick google of "MSSQL OR Performance" suggests the problem is more universal. Probably due to implementation optimizations vs effect; abstractly, `WHERE` is supposed to happen after everything in the `FROM`, but to make things quicker most SQL implementations filter what they can early by using the where conditions first. However, in the case of OR, you cannot apply both first as that would in effect be an AND. It _could_ try to start from both directions and effectively do the standard UNION, but that is likely much easier said than done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why is `OR` so slow, but `UNION` is so fast?

Do you understand why `UNION` is fast?  Because it can use two separate indexes to good advantage, and gather some result rows from each part of the `UNION`, then combine the results together.

But why can't `OR` do that?  Simply put, the Optimizer is not smart enough to try that angle.

In your case, the tests are on different tables; this leads to radically different query plans (see `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`) for the two parts of the `UNION`.  Each can be well optimized, so each is fast.

Assuming each part delivers only a few rows, the subsequent overhead of `UNION` is minor -- namely to gather the two small sets of row, dedup them (if you use `UNION DISTINCT` instead of `UNION ALL`), and deliver the results.

Meanwhile, the `OR` query effectively gather all combinations of the two tables, *then* filtered out based on the two parts of the `OR`.  The intermediate stage may involve a huge temp table, only to have most of the rows tossed.

(Another example of inflate-deflate is `JOINs` + `GROUP BY`.  The workarounds are different.)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest writing the query using `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM transactions t
WHERE t.id_trans = '5440073'
UNION ALL
SELECT t.*
FROM transactions t JOIN
     integration it 
     ON it.id_trans = t.id_trans
WHERE t.id_trans <> '5440073' AND
      it.id_integration = '439580587';
```

Note:  If the ids are really numbers (and not strings), then drop the single quotes.  Mixing types can sometimes confuse the optimizer and prevent the use of indexes.

Comment: I still not found why the OR clause takes so long to complete

Comment: `OR` often prevents the use of indexes.

Comment: @RickJames . . . Ahem, `t.id_trans <> '5440073'` in the second subquery.